# XML and XSL using transformXML(xml, xsl)

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, xml

Im trying to make html content for an triggered sent email. The client can only delivery the xml in one format, and I cant get my XSL to work, when the xml have prefixes. The Salesforce documentation is very weak on how to make the xsl correct.

XML sample:

```
<z:anyType xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trifork.BasicOrder.Service" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="d1p1:OrderChangedMessage">
   <d1p1:AdvantageBurnedPoints i:nil="true" />
   <d1p1:AdvantageEarnedPoints>0</d1p1:AdvantageEarnedPoints>
   <d1p1:Discount>0</d1p1:Discount>
   <d1p1:OrderId>10014</d1p1:OrderId>
   <d1p1:OrderLines>
      <d1p1:OrderChangedMessage.OrderLine>
         <d1p1:Number>2</d1p1:Number>
         <d1p1:ProductName>Morgentilbud Dagmartærte (10+1+1)</d1p1:ProductName>
         <d1p1:ProductShortDescription i:nil="true" />
         <d1p1:Subtotal>10000</d1p1:Subtotal>
         <d1p1:UnitPrice>5000</d1p1:UnitPrice>
      </d1p1:OrderChangedMessage.OrderLine>
      <d1p1:OrderChangedMessage.OrderLine>
         <d1p1:Number>2</d1p1:Number>
         <d1p1:ProductName>Morgentilbud Dagmartærte (10+1+1)</d1p1:ProductName>
         <d1p1:ProductShortDescription i:nil="true" />
         <d1p1:Subtotal>10000</d1p1:Subtotal>
         <d1p1:UnitPrice>5000</d1p1:UnitPrice>
      </d1p1:OrderChangedMessage.OrderLine>
   </d1p1:OrderLines>
   <d1p1:PaymentStatus>Captured</d1p1:PaymentStatus>
   <d1p1:PaymentType>MobilePay</d1p1:PaymentType>
   <d1p1:PickupDate>2016-04-29 00:00:00Z</d1p1:PickupDate>
   <d1p1:PickupTime>7:00:00</d1p1:PickupTime>
   <d1p1:ShopAdresse>Frederiksalle 22-24</d1p1:ShopAdresse>
   <d1p1:ShopCity>Arhus C</d1p1:ShopCity>
   <d1p1:ShopCvr i:nil="true" />
   <d1p1:ShopName>føtex Frederiks Alle</d1p1:ShopName>
   <d1p1:ShopPhone>86186000</d1p1:ShopPhone>
   <d1p1:ShopZip>8000</d1p1:ShopZip>
   <d1p1:TotalAmount>10000</d1p1:TotalAmount>
   <d1p1:UserAccountId>sample string 1</d1p1:UserAccountId>
   <d1p1:UserAdvantageId i:nil="true" />
   <d1p1:UserEmail i:nil="true" />
   <d1p1:UserName>Mikkel K</d1p1:UserName>
   <d1p1:UserPhone>00000000</d1p1:UserPhone>
</z:anyType>
```

XSL would look something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="z:anyType">
    <xsl:value-of select="d1p1:ShopName" />
    <xsl:value-of select="d1p1:ShopCity" />
    <xsl:for-each select="d1p1:OrderLines/d1p1:OrderChangedMessage.OrderLine">
        <xsl:value-of select="d1p1:ProductName" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can see another Question using BuildRowsetFromXML(), I'm not sure if this is the right path to go to. My only other option is to ask Salesforce for help.

Comment: Have you tried developing the XSL outside of SFMC?  Like in [MS Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255602.aspx)?  It's a whole lot easier than trying to get it to work in SFMC.